# Facebook: Invalid hash key

Tags: android-facebook

I am using three device to test Facebook login. Invalid hash key shown when test on Lenovo k8 note. I have place release and debug key on Facebook console.
To generate release key-

> keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore
>    | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl sha1 -binary
>   | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl base64

To generate deubg key

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "in.technitab.fitmode",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
        }
```